# Problem in representing missing values in .arff format

Tags: csv, weka, arff

While trying to convert a csv file to a arff file, the missing values (represented by ? in the csv) are not properly converted. While using csv2arff to convert a csv to arff, the column containing missing values has all of its values wrapped in quotes, and the datatype changes from numeric as well.

Can anybody tell me how to convert a csv file with ? in place of missing values to a arff file that conserves the datatype of the column as numeric ?

Comment: via what programming language?

Comment: via python. I installed the csv2arff package using pip

Comment: I actually solved the problem. I am no longer converting the files. Just manually changing the format of the csv file to match that of arff. That is what worked at the end.

Comment: didn't know that would work, i would have just said, flag which values should have been what type and cast.